# Как получить данные из JSON в Ruby

Tags: json, ruby

Есть вот такой вот json

```
"threads": 
[{"posts": 
{"banned":0, 
"closed":0, 
"comment":}}]
```

Как получить отсюда данные из `comment`?

У меня вот такой код

```
require 'rubygems' 
require 'json' 
require 'httparty' 
file = File.read('test.json') 
data_hash = JSON.parse(file) 
posts_count = data_hash['posts_count'] 
posts = data_hash['posts'] 
threads = data_hash['threads'] 
length = threads.length 
p threads
```

Что добавить, чтобы всё работало
Потому что когда я ввожу

```
comment = data_hash['comment'] 
p comment
```

он выдаёт `nil`

Comment: Добавь в конце `p data_hash` и прикрепи вывод к вопросу.

Comment: Структура точно правильно указана?
Если да, то и не должно выводиться ничего. В корне (читай в data_hash) нет поля `comment`.

Comment: Нужна структура файла и описание того, что нужно из неё получить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Верный JSON код такой:

```
a='{"threads": 
   [{"posts": 
   {"banned":0, 
   "closed":0, 
   "comment":""}}]}'
```

1. Не должно быть раскрытого словаря (`Hash`) от корня дерева,т.е. он должен быть заключён в фигурные скобки: `{}`.
2. Не должно быть отсутствующих значений, как у поля `comment`, там должен быть либо `null`, либо пустая строка.

Вышеприведённый код разбирается верно:

```
JSON.parse(a)
# => {"threads"=>[{"posts"=>{"banned"=>0, "closed"=>0, "comment"=>""}}]}
```